# Why weren't Thor and Hulk present in the movie Captain America: Civil War?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-civil-war

I remember faintly that they were referenced in the movie couple of times.

But where were they while all the civil war was happening? Why weren't they part of the civil war? Were they at least aware that something like civil war is happening?

What does the story in the comics say? Is there an explanation given there?

Comment: At the end of Age of Ultron, Banner goes into hiding as he's been involved in too many incidents where his rage causes death and destruction to innocents.  Thor is 'elsewhere' but seriously the events of Civil War are relatively minor compared to the world ending events of the Thor or Avengers movies.  Captain America movies center on interesting but less overpowered bad guys.

Comment: out-of-universe reason: They weren't in the Civil War comics because reasons/spoilers.

Comment: @miltonaut no, because hulk and Thor are too over powered. That's what the director said.

Comment: @miltonaut can you add it as an answer?

Comment: @iandotkelly - at the end of "Age of Ultron" Thor said he was troubled by the appearance of more than just one Infinity Stone and was going to go off and investigate what was going on, which you were probably aware of, but I figured I'd add that trivia bit.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They are busy in Asgard and or another planet, during the events of Ragnarok, the Third Thor film. This is hinted at in Civil War by Senator "Thunderbolt" Ross, when he asks where Hulk and Thor are, as if they were missing atomic bombs (funny, the US military has lost multiple atomic bombs).

Any further information is pending the films release, which will undoubtedly reference Civil War some way. [But Ruffalo has stated in a tongue in cheek way:](http://www.ew.com/article/2016/05/24/thor-ragnarok-mark-ruffalo-buddy-road-movie-cate-blanchett)

> **“It’s an intergalactic buddy road movie with Banner and Thor,”** Ruffalo told Entertainment Tonight at a press junket for his latest movie, Now You See Me 2.
>
> The actor added fans will see “a lot more Hulk” this time around, doing what Bruce Banner/The Big Green Guy does best. When Now You See Me 2 costar Woody Harrelson asked if the Hulk will be even “Hulk-ier” in this new film, Ruffalo responded, “The Hulk gets Hulk-ier. The Hulk Hulks out. Hulk-ier and bigger.”

*So, they were on a road trip.*

Comment: maybe you can add that team thor video in here

Comment: @cde I have edited the question asking for a reference from the comics. See if you can address that.

Comment: @palebluedot that's borderline off topic, but the answer is... it doesnt. Thor and Hulks involvement in Civil war were limited, and hulk was not part of Ragnorak, and Thor was not part of Planet hulk. Ragnorak movie covers both in some aspects, but planet hulk revolved around hulk banished by the illuminati,  which included Xavier and Reed Richard. Which MCU lacks. So the comics have nothing to do with the movie events other than minor inspiration.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to [CDE's answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/60817/48480), Marvel actually released a video answering what Thor and The Hulk were doing during Civil War.

Comment: That video was more of a joke