# How did S.H.I.E.L.D. know about Dr. Strange in Captain America: The Winter Soldier?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-the-winter-soldier

In *Captain America: The Winter Soldier*, how did S.H.I.E.L.D. know about Dr Strange?

It is mentioned in the scene on the rooftop that existence of Bruce Banner, and Steven Strange have changed the game.

So have to assume timing of movies should have in the movie universe (reversed in release of movies)

1. Dr Strange
2. Captain America Civil War

At what point S.H.I.E.L.D. learned about Dr. Strange?

Comment: Heavily related: [When is Doctor Strange actually set?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/62872/49)

Comment: I believe you're actually referring to a rooftop scene from Captain America: The Winter Soldier.

Comment: @DaniellYancey : Yes you are right, i got the movies mixed up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We don't know *precisely* but we do know that SHIELD/HYDRA have been aware of Steven Strange since **before** *Captain America: The Winter Soldier* even if only as a potential problem/threat using Arnim Zola's algorithm.

Since they are aware of him it's logical that they were, at least, keeping him under some form of surveillance (or at least monitoring) so they would be aware of his emergence.

After all, that's what SHIELD now does, monitor and catalog *gifted* people....at least in the TV series and, by extension, in the MCU as a whole.

---

Equally, Thor is aware of Dr. Strange as we know from the post-credit scene in the *Dr. Strange* movie...so while *that* scene (we think) takes place after *Civil War* we know that the bulk of the movie takes place before it.

So, it's possible that Thor has kept SHIELD informed before [he disappeared with Banner](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/60816/why-werent-thor-and-hulk-present-in-the-movie-captain-america-civil-war?rq=1).

Answer (score 5):

Before the events of (and during the beginning of) the film *Doctor Strange*, Dr. Steven Strange was an incredibly-skilled, highly-accomplished neurosurgeon. It is likely that this was enough to put him on SHIELD's radar.